# Trouble populating an SQLite FTS table on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, full-text-search

I have looked at the other answers, but I haven't seen any that answers the problem that I have. I am more interested in, is the way I am doing it ever going to work, and if so how; than here are alternate methods. The project is for mobile devices using objective c.

First I create the regular table and then the FTS table, as below.

```
NSString *searchTable = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %@ (%@ INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, %@ TEXT, %@ TEXT, %@ TEXT)", gPsalmVersesTableName, gIDKey , gNameKey, gVerseKey, gTextKey];
if (sqlite3_exec(mInfoDB, [searchTable UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSLog(@"Failed to create table %@", gPsalmVersesTableName);

NSString *virtualTable = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %@ USING fts4 (content='%@', %@)",gFTSPsalmVersesTableName, gPsalmVersesTableName, gTextKey];
if (sqlite3_exec(mInfoDB, [virtualTable UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSLog(@"Failed to create table %@", gFTSPsalmVersesTableName);
```

Then I populate the regular table (gPsalmVersesTableName), I have confirmed that this step works correctly. By downloading the app content and reading the table in a database viewer.

When I populate the FTS table, I get no errors, however no data is added to the table.

```
if (sqlite3_open([mDataBaseName UTF8String], &mInfoDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        @try
        {
            NSString *rebuildSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@(%@) VALUES('rebuild')", gFTSPsalmVersesTableName, gFTSPsalmVersesTableName];

            int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(mInfoDB, [rebuildSQL UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL);
            NSLog(@"%s", sqlite3_errstr(result));
        }
        @finally
        {
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(mInfoDB);
        }
    }
```

I have implemented the same code on Android and it works fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlite3_prepare_v2()` does not execute a statement; `sqlite3_step()` does.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is funny how sometime you can miss the obvious.